# fetch all the termstores from a current site in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, term-store, typescript

```
public taxonomy() {
    SP.SOD.registerSod('sp.taxonomy.js',SP.Utilities.Utility.getLayoutsPageUrl('sp.taxonomy.js'));  
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.taxonomy.js','SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession',function() {
        var rest:ListItemOperations=new ListItemOperations();
        var tSession =SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(rest.context);
        var termStores=tSession.get_termStores();
        rest.context.load(tSession);    
        rest.context.load(termStores);    
        rest.context.executeQueryAsync(function() {
            var termStoreEnum=termStores.getEnumerator();
            var termStore = "Term Stores: /n";
            while(termStoreEnum.moveNext){
                var currentTermStore=termStoreEnum.get_current();
                console.log(currentTermStore.get_name());
                var termStoreId=currentTermStore.get_id();
                var termStoreName=currentTermStore.get_name();
                termStore+="Name:"+termStoreName+"Id:"+termStoreId;
                console.log(termStore);
            }
       }
    }
}
```

I am using the above code is for fetching all the termstores from a  current site in sharepoint. But the `currentTermStore` shows an undefined error.

What changes shall I make to get all the termstores?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change your iterator. JSOM array list enumerator doesn't have `moveNext` property, you should use a method instead:

```
while(termStoreEnum.moveNext()) {...}
```